# Calling another method inside another method?

Tags: java, methods

I am new into Java and I am trying to understand a piece of code:

```
public class Image {
...
public float getPixel(int height, int width) {
    return data[height][width];
}
public void setPixel(float value, int height, int width) {
    if (value > getMax())
        value = getMax();
    if (value < 0)
        value = 0;

    data[height][width] = value;
}

private Image(String magicNumber, int height, int width, float max) {
    this.magicNumber = magicNumber;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.max = max;
    data = new float[height][width];
}
...
public Image clone() {
    Image clone = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());
    for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++) {
            clone.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j); /** trying to understand this line */
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

What does `clone.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);` exactly do? And what I mostly don't understand is what `clone.` which is before `setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

This method is creating a copy of the object which the method is called on.
The first "clone" is name of the method and the second (which is also the third) is an instance of `Image` which should be returned.

```
clone.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);
```

This method is setting the pixels of result object (which is an `Image`) by using the current object equivalent properties.

> And what I mostly don't understand is what `clone.` which is before `setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j);` is doing?

As I said above, it's just the instance name which the method `setPixel` is from and called on.
`getPixel(i, j)` is calling on the current object so it's equivalent of `this.getPixel(i, j)`.

Comment: But `setPixel` is from the class `Image`. I still don't understand what `.clone` is doing... Could you explain that to me in other words?

Comment: @JamesH `clone` is an instnace of `Image` and you want to call `setPixel` on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should understand the difference between Class,Instance and Method. secondly i think it is a bad practice to name an instance and a method with the same name `clone`.

In this example you have one Class `Image`, one constructor  `private Image(String magicNumber, int height, int width, float max)` which is used implicitly when you create new object using the operator `new`, you also have the method `public float getPixel(int height, int width)` which is used to retrieve the value of one pixel at certain coordinates  `(int height, int width)` , another method void `setPixel(float value, int height, int width)`  which is used to set the value of  pixel at certain coordinates, the last method `public Image clone()` it should be refactored to be

```
public Image clone() {
    Image imageInstance = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());
    for (int i = 0; i < getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getWidth(); j++) {
            imageInstance.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j); /** trying to understand this line */
        }
    }

    return imageInstance;
}
```

i just changed the name of the `Image` instance to be `imageInstance`, in fact this method is very simple and straightforward, it is just create new object of `Image` then loop over all the pixels in the current object and copy that pixel into the same location of the `imageInstance`

Now the line `imageInstance.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j); /** trying to understand this line */` it contains 2 methods call `setPixel` and `getPixel` the first one to be executed is the inner one `getPixel` it will retrieve the value of the current pixel, the the outer method will be called `setPixel` which will use the value from the `getPixel` method to set the value of the pixel at coordinates  `i, j` of the `imageInstance`

the final result will be an exact copy of the current `Image` instance

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean for every Loop when I do `imageInstance.setPixel(getPixel(i, j), i, j)` , `imageInstance` gets updated?

Comment: @JamesH, Yes for every iteration the imageInstance will be updated

Comment: OK. Last two questions: 1) I have a method from a different class which returns an Image and does `Image filtered = image.clone();`. What does this line exactly do. And 2) I want to acess all the methods from the class `Image`. Can I do this by  `Image name = new Image(getMagicNumber(), getHeight(), getWidth(), getMax());` and does this give me the right to acces all methods in `Image`?